# Form model binding in Laravelcollective, a default checked checkbox never shows unchecked

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-5, laravelcollective

Laravel 5.5, Laravelcollective 5.4

On my edit page the checkbox is always showing checked, regardless of state in database. (Have confirmed it's working as intended without default checked.)

I use the same form fields for my create route, and would like the default to be checked.

```
 {{ Form::model($client, ['route' => ['clients.update', $client->id], 'method' => 'patch']) }}
 {{ Form::checkbox('active', 'Yes', true) }}
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation on form model binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#form-model-binding)

> So, the priority looks like this:
>
> 1. Session Flash Data (Old Input)
> 2. Explicitly Passed Value
> 3. Model Attribute Data

Note that the explicitly Passed Value seems to not be a default fallback but the actual value that will be used if provided (regardless of model). Therefore that seems to be the intended behaviour.

Update: As discussed in the comments, a solution to allow fallback values in the case where there's no model set is to use:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', 'Yes', isset($client)?null:true) }}
```

Comment: @MikeThrussell Well the problem is that you're trying to use the `Form::model` both in cases  where you have a model and in cases that you don't (which is not what it's intended to do). You could do something like `Form::checkbox('active', 'Yes', $client !==null?null:true)` or something to that effect

Comment: Had to go with `{{ Form::checkbox('active', 'Yes', isset($client)?null:true)  }}` as no `$client` variable set on the create form.

Comment: @MikeThrussell I've updated the answer to reflect this